# how to create production SSR build with sparatcus CCV2

Tags: spartacus-storefront

some of my functonality is breaking in prdo build with SSR but working fine with local SSR build.
I am not able to create the exact prod build command.
here is my dev build command

```
"ng": "ng",
"sonar": "sonar-scanner",
"start": "ng serve",
"start:ssl": "ng serve --ssl --disable-host-check",
"build": "node --max-http-header-size=16384 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"dev:ssr": "node --max-http-header-size=16384 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run mystore:serve-ssr",
"serve:ssr": "node --max-http-header-size=16384 dist/mystore/server/main.js",
"serve:dev:ssr": "node --max-http-header-size=16384 dist/mystore-server/main.js",
"build:dev:ssr": "node --max-http-header-size=16384 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build && node --max-http-header-size=16384 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run mystore:server",
"build:ssr": "(cp server.prod.ts server.ts || copy server.prod.ts server.ts) && node --max-http-header-size=16384 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod && node --max-http-header-size=16384 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run mystore:server:production && mv dist/mystore-server/main.js dist/server.js || move dist\\mystore-server\\main.js dist\\server.js",
"prerender": "ng run mystore:prerender"
```

and the combined command I ran is

> yarn build:dev:ssr & yarn serve:dev:ssr

I need how this replace Backend OCC url in the build

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 4.0, you may need to set the `CX_BASE_URL` as an environment variable when you build. There is an article here about the way the OCC url is handled between 3.0 and 4.0: https://chowdera.com/2021/08/20210807233507800o.html

Comment: I am using 3.4 version , I only need the local build command to run in local , I can set baseURL in environment.ts file and it picks it up from there for DEV mode. but i have null for OccBaseURL